# rules for generated files with variable part in filename

Tags: gnu-make, automake

There're source files: `a.asn1`, `b.asn1`

first I need to preprocess them to add a prefix to identifiers (different prefix for different files).

```
./prefixASN1.pl -file "foo.asn1" -prefix PREF-
```

does so and outputs the result to `PREF-foo.asn1`

Then I need to generate C parsers from PREF-foo.asn1.

```
./snacc -mm PREF-foo.asn1
```

will create foo.c and foo.h (filenames without prefix)

How to achive same behavior as this long makefile has:

```
a.c a.h: AAA-a.asn1
    ./snacc -mm $<
# serialize
a.h: a.c

b.c b.h: BBB-b.asn1
    ./snacc -mm $<
# serialize
b.h: b.c

AAA-a.asn1: a.asn1
    ./prefixASN1.pl -file $< -prefix AAA-

BBB-b.asn1: b.asn1
    ./prefixASN1.pl -file $< -prefix BBB-
```

with something shorter, like this:

```
# ??? set PREFIX=AAA for a
# ??? set PREFIX=BBB for b

%.c %.h: $(PREFIX)%.asn1
    ./snacc -mm $<
# serialize
???

$(PREFIX)%.asn1: %.asn1
    ./prefixASN1.pl -file $< -prefix $(PREFIX)
```

?

I'm using autotools and GNU make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that it's more correct to have same prefix in all files.

- Renamed the source specs to `%.unprefixed.asn1`
- modified the perl script to allow custom output filename
- defined several `ASN1_PREFIX_<stem>` variables:

_

```
ASN1_PREFIX_a = AAA-
ASN1_PREFIX_b = BBB-
```

- added rules:

_

```
%.asn1: %.unprefixed.asn1`
    $(PREFIXASN1) -file $< -prefix "$(ASN1_PREFIX_$*)" -outfile $@

%.c %.h: %.asn1
    ...
```

_

To pass variable prefix to the rule I prefered `Computed Variable Names` over `Target-specific Variable Values`